# Rake doesn't know how to build tasks: default or minitest

Tags: ruby, rake, minitest

I built a gem a while back and did not include any tests (shame on me). I've since attempted to redress this by including minitest, but I'm getting stuck right out of the gate with the following error:

> Don't know how to build task 'default'

Here's my **Rakefile**

```
require 'rake/testtask'

Rake::TestTask.new do |t|
  t.test_files = FileList['test/*_test.rb']
end
```

And the dummy file in `test/unit_test.rb`

```
require 'minitest/autorun'

class TestPackage < MiniTest::Unit::TestCase

  def test
    assert_equal 10, Array.new(10).size
  end
end
```

If I change the Rakefile to include `task :default => 'minitest'` the error message changes to `Don't know how to build task 'minitest'`

`rake --trace` seems to just direct me back to the parts of the Rake gem that handle task invocation. No clues that I can see:

```
~/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task_manager.rb:49:in `[]'
~/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:115:in `invoke_task'
~/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:94:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
~/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:94:in `each'
~/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in top_level'
~/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
~/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:88:in `top_level'
~/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:66:in `block in run'
~/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
~/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
~/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p286/bin/rake:32:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Rake tasks are always named. The `Rake::TestTask` task is named `test`, so if you run `rake test` it will run your tests.

To make `Rake::TestTask` your default task just include:

```
task :default => :test
```

in your `Rakefile`.

http://rake.rubyforge.org/Rake/TestTask.html